# Turn off intra prediction in h265

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, hevc

I'm using ffmpeg to encode images into h265 (HEVC) videos and I'm wondering - is there a way to turn off the intra prediction, so that only inter prediction is used? (EDIT: or force using inter prediction?) I couldn't find it among these commands https://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/cli.html.

Comment: I don't think you can. How would you encode the first frame without intra prediction ?

Comment: Well, maybe something like "turn off for all but first frame", or at least "force to use inter prediction"...

Comment: Even with "--keyint -1" (infinite GOP, only one keyframe at start), the encoder will still encode some CUs in an intra way because it will consider they're more bit-efficient than the inter version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to turn off intra prediction.

At first frame, it's must be coding with intra mode because it have no reference frame.

At inter frame. it depends on RDO process to select final mode. so, at inter frame, a cu with intra mode means the RD cost is smallest with intra mode.

so, when turn off the intra mode, the rd performance may degree .

thank you for read.

Answer (score 0):

I think he means that the reference frame will have no coding at all just a bunch of CTUs the one after the previous (no dependencies) just as a still image. There is no option in the HM test model encoder but you may change the behaviour inside the source code.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. Inter prediction use correlation between pictures (frames) to make motion-compensated prediction. So in order to make inter prediction you must have reference frame at first place. For this reason first frame inside GOP is always Intra and this Intra frame is used for Inter prediction.